# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to create ionic 3 custom native plugin. I have one more aar file which I need to add that aar file through plugin. I did in a same way. But now I am facing issue while running the code through android studio. I can see below error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources, :CordovaLib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :CordovaLib:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
/Users/mobilesolution/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/widget-debug.aar/bcf9996b5e370c6ae472fa0793a77af4/res/values/values.xml
Error:(62, 5) error: style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka io.ionic.starter:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
Error:(62, 5) error: style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka io.ionic.starter:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
Error:resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light (aka io.ionic.starter:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light) not found.
Error:resource style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar (aka io.ionic.starter:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar) not found.
/Users/mobilesolution/Documents/Vishal Gole/LiquidPay/IonicApp/PayApp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Error:(61) style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka io.ionic.starter:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
Error:(62) style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka io.ionic.starter:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
Error:resource style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light (aka io.ionic.starter:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light) not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s
Information:12 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Please do let me know what am I doing wrong.

Please do let me know if you need any other information.